# jquery-generated DOM elements event handler challenge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically building a page using jquery/ajax/json:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#dv_tools").append("<ul></ul>");
    $.getJSON( "assets/json/tools.json", function( data ) {
      var tools = [];
      $.each( data.tools, function( key, val ) {
          tools[val["id"]]=val;
      });
    
      $.each( data.audiences, function( key, val ) {
          // selector list
          $("<li><label><input type=radio name=audience value="+val["id"]+">"+val["name"]+"</label></li>").appendTo("#audience_list");
          
          // selection content
          $("<li id=cat"+val["id"]+" class=vcat></li>").html(val["id"] + "::" + val["name"]).appendTo("#dv_tools ul");
      });
    });
     
    $("input[name=audience]:radio").change(function () {
        $("#dv_tools ul").find('li').each(function() {
            if($(this).prop('id')=="cat"+$("input[name=audience]:checked").val()) $(this).show();
            else $(this).hide();
            alert("here!");
        });
    });
    $('input[name=audience]:radio[value=2]').attr('checked', 'checked');     
});
```

```html
<ul id="audience_list"></ul>
...
<div id="dv_tools"></div>
```

What it is suppose to do is to build a radio button selector list, after clicking on each item the content below should change dynamically.

DOM is being built correctly: I see my list and content below, no problem. But the event handler is not firing...

So this portion of the code doesn't work:

```js
    $("input[name=audience]:radio").change(function () {
        $("#dv_tools ul").find('li').each(function() {
            if($(this).prop('id')=="cat"+$("input[name=audience]:checked").val()) $(this).show();
            else $(this).hide();
            alert("here!"); //not working :(
        });
    });
    $('input[name=audience]:radio[value=2]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

It does work, however, when I have my  list elements hardcoded in HTML directly. I feel like I am missing something simple and it prob comes from my shallow understanding of jquery/js.

Thank you

Adding json:

```
{
"audiences": [
    {"id":"1","name":"Plan Sponsor (existing)","tools":"1,2,3,9"},
    {"id":"2","name":"Plan Sponsor (prospect)","tools":"4,6,2,3"},
    {"id":"3","name":"Professional Employer Organization (PEO) (existing)","tools":"1,2,3,7"},
    {"id":"4","name":"Professional Employer Organization (PEO) (prospect)","tools":"1,2,3,5"}        
],
"tools": [
    {"id":"1","name":"tool1","desc":"some description"},
    {"id":"2","name":"tool2","desc":"some description"},
    {"id":"3","name":"tool3","desc":"some description"},
    {"id":"4","name":"tool4","desc":"some description"},
    {"id":"5","name":"tool5","desc":"some description"}
]
```

}

Comment: Can you explain this statement a different way? "It does work, however, when I have my list hardcoded in directly." Also, if you can supply a bit of your JSON, that can help with debugging.

Comment: You have to debug this one step at a time. If you add `alert("changed");` after `$("input[name=audience]:radio").change(function () {` what happens when you click the radio buttons? Does this alert fire? If so, then we can move to the next line, but I suspect the problem is here. Any errors in the console?

Comment: alert doesn't fire, no errors in console

Comment: hardcoded in HTML = I have static <ul id="audience_list"></ul> list with all static <li> elements present vs. building it in jquery

Comment: I've added json to my question

Comment: This is basically your exact code except with the JSON stored as a variable and seems to work perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/yzr2262v/3/

Comment: What ended up working?

Comment: I've had to add     $("input[name=audience]:radio").change(function () {
        $("#dv_tools ul").find('li').each(function() {
            if($(this).prop('id')=="cat"+$("input[name=audience]:checked").val()) $(this).show();
            else $(this).hide();
            alert("here!"); //not working :(
        });
    });
    $('input[name=audience]:radio[value=2]').attr('checked', 'checked'); inside the getJSON callback as Uri Hartmann suggested and as it was in your working code.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getJSON is asynchronous, which means that your suspicious code (starting with $("input[name=audience]:radio").change) is executed BEFORE the getJSON is completed, and therefore before your radio buttons were created, so they are not selected for your event listener.

Try to move that code INSIDE the getJSON callback, right after creating the radio buttons, and it'll work like a charm!